# Side by Side Plotting Instead of Panel Plotting on R Base System

Tags: r, plot, panel, radix

Sorry if this question was asked before but I couldn't find a similar post.
I am trying to create a panel plot on R's base system. But R Studio shows my plots side by side not on a panel. So I tried to copy some codes from internet and it is still showing charts side by side. For example this codes has to create a panel plot right?

```
library(datasets)
par(mfrow = c(1, 3), mar = c(4, 4, 2, 1), oma = c(0, 0, 2, 0))
with(airquality, {
   plot(Wind, Ozone, main = "Ozone and Wind")
   plot(Solar.R, Ozone, main = "Ozone and Solar Radiation")
   plot(Temp, Ozone, main = "Ozone and Temperature")
   mtext("Ozone and Weather in New York City", outer = TRUE)
})
```

But stupid R studio is creating plots side by side.
Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Probably it will be ok if I restart R session but I don't want to loose my loaded variables. Any guesses for this issue?
By the way I created some plots using lattice and ggplot2 on same session (I don't know if it effects each other.)

Comment: Try running `dev.off()` first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run your code in the console, you will get a panel plot. Run this code in console:

```
library(datasets)
par(mfrow = c(1, 3), mar = c(4, 4, 2, 1), oma = c(0, 0, 2, 0))
with(airquality, {
  plot(Wind, Ozone, main = "Ozone and Wind")
  plot(Solar.R, Ozone, main = "Ozone and Solar Radiation")
  plot(Temp, Ozone, main = "Ozone and Temperature")
  mtext("Ozone and Weather in New York City", outer = TRUE)
})
```

Output:

[image]

If you run this in Rmarkdown, you will also get a panel plot. Here is the code:

````
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r}
library(datasets)
par(mfrow = c(1, 3), mar = c(4, 4, 2, 1), oma = c(0, 0, 2, 0))
with(airquality, {
  plot(Wind, Ozone, main = "Ozone and Wind")
  plot(Solar.R, Ozone, main = "Ozone and Solar Radiation")
  plot(Temp, Ozone, main = "Ozone and Temperature")
  mtext("Ozone and Weather in New York City", outer = TRUE)
})
```
````

Output in pdf:

[image]

Comment: And how can I get the panel plot on R markdown file to knitr into pdf later?

Comment: @milikest I added code to my answer above. It actually says that if you just run the code in Rmarkdown with pdf as output, it will be a panel plot.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer. And also I appreciate for your quick respond.